# How to self-answer when the question is closed?

Tags: support, closing, answers, self-answer

My [lowest scored question (as of now)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/382418/i-cant-enter-cubecraft-servers) is recently solved by me and I wanted to self-answer it, but thanks to the given fact of game piracy, it was closed off-topic.

How can I self-answer my question if it is closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. A question is closed because it's not a good fit for our site. So if the question cannot be fixed to be acceptable for the site, you cannot answer it .